# How do I build a class that extends the class of one of its __init__ inputs

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance

I've written a wrapper class around some machine learning models (from sklearn) but I want to expose the underlying model attributes and methods directly for compatibility with other code.

As a toy example...

```
class LogWrapper(BaseEstimator):

    def __init__(self, model):
        self.model = model

    def fit(self, X, y):
        y_log = np.log(y)
        self.model.fit(X, y_log)

    def predict(self, X):
        y_log_pred = self.model.predict(X)
        y_pred = np.exp(y_log_pred)
        return y_pred

# Then you can do 

my_model = LogWrapper(DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=4))
```

However, I would like to access the `model`'s methods without having to write code of the form

```
my_model.model.decision_path(X)
```

I'd prefer to write

```
my_model.decision_path(X)
```

The desired behaviour is comparable to having the `LogWrapper` class inherit from the class of `model` passed to the **init** rather than from BaseEstimator.

Comment: What you want is not inheritance, but python's data model makes it pretty easy to delegate in a wrapper class. See the accepted answer in the linked duplicate

Comment: so in your case, you'd simply want something like `def __getattr__(self, attr): return getattr(self.model, attr)`

Comment: ...although wrapper classes like this that have if conditions in init are rightly frowned upon

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D what do you mean? which class are you referring to? What condition?

Comment: Oh not your answer - this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56747128/281545

Comment: But now I look more carefully the condition is in the factory - ignore my commnet